# Changing ControlPort in slurm deployment on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, slurm

I am having trouble with my slurm cluster that I deployed on google cloud platform.  In my slurmctld.log file, I get this error:

> error: slurm_persist_conn_open_without_init: failed to open persistent
>   connection to google-gcp-controller:6819: Connection refused

So I looked at `sacctmgr list cluster WOLimits`

> Cluster     ControlHost  ControlPort   RPC
>
> ---
>
> google-gcp      10.10.0.2         6817  8192

The ControlPort doesn't match between the error and the output of sacctmgr.  Is this why my jobs are failing?  How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

6819 is the accounting storage port; the `slurmdbd` daemon is supposed to listen to that port. So most probably this deamon is not running, or even not configured. See the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/accounting.html) for more information.